# print the output of a thread in a new window in c

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to print the output of each thread in a new window.
Where as the main function outputs to the first terminal.
My code is in c language.
Please help me.Thank you!

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are on Linux as you've tagged this pthreads? Also you must give a lot more context. What do you mean exactly by "window", terminal window, GUI window? As in you want to spawn multiple threads, each writing to a terminal of their own? And finally, if you have code, please post the relevant parts.

Comment: In a console-based program you can not just open new terminals and use them for your `stdout`. You can use something like `ncurses` to split the current terminal into "windows", and use one per thread with special output functions.

Comment: @Skurmedel  Pthreads is POSIX and runs on platforms other than Linux, including OS X, and even Windows (add-on libraries).  That said, the question is exceedingly vague.  You ask for help, but don't show us any of your own work, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: I'm on Linux.window means new terminal window.
i have multiple threads in my program and each thread has to write the output in a new terminal window @Skurmedel

Comment: I'm writing a raw socket program where i have created a pthread for each protocol tcp,udp,icmp...my program captures packets and displays them.i want to display each type of packet in seperate window. @Randy Howard

Comment: So you want to write an X app? I *strongly* suggest a framework  such as Qt. Believe me. If all you know is "I want separate windows...", the last thing you wanna do is bite off Xlib.

Comment: Its not any app.Its an assignment.

Comment: @Randy Howard: Notice the wording in my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: You can't.

Long answer is, you can but it's a lot of work. Basically you have to somehow open a window and attach a pseudo-terminal to it, but one without a shell.

A shorter solution would be to use processes instead of threads. Then you can split your program into two or more programs, one to create the processes and one or more to do the work you previously had the threads for. In the main program you `fork` and then `exec` the worker programs.

The simplest solution if you must use threads, then it's to use `ncurses` to split the current terminal window into separate "windows" for each thread.